# Android App Widget - How fill a ListView in an Objcet that is in a Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, widget, remoteview

I need a widget that shows a listview. And in this listview i need other listviews with string items. How can i implement this?

Should look like the google keep widget.

http://static5.businessinsider.com/image/549b04ed6da811c3525b4a58-1200/the-google-keep-widget-is-a-great-way-to-quickly-see-your-to-do-list.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not advisable/supported to have two scrollable lists in the same direction nested inside each other, it's hard for the user to know whether they will be scrolling the inner or outer view. I don't think those inner Google Keep preview entries are individually scrollable. They're probably LinearLayouts.

Comment: Okay, but how can I fill this LinearLayout dynamically?

Comment: Loop round your items and call addView()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View)